# problems with Hibernate's integration in Spring

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I have a simple Java application and I'm trying to integrate Hibernate in Spring but it seems that the Spring configuration file can't find the *.hbm.xml (the mapping resource):
I have a file named persistence-context.xml that I use it as a Spring config file and I have the following bean declared:

org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

But is being thrown the exception:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [pool.hbm.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
I've even tried giving the mapping resources property an absolute path value. It doesn't work.
Thank you!

UPDATE:
My Spring conf file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value='jdbc:mysql://localhost/bestofs_seinfeld' />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="futifuti825300" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="mappingResources" value="pool.hbm.xml" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref bean="mySessionFactory"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="voteDao" class="bestofs.persistence.HibernatePoolDao">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate">
        <ref bean="hibernateTemplate"/>    
    </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

And my pool.hbm.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="bestofs.persistence.PoolBean" table="sein_pool">
    <id name="idVote" column="ID_Vote">
        <generator class="assigned"/>
    </id>

    <property name="IdActor">
        <column name="ID_Actor"/>
    </property>
    <property name="IdUser">
        <column name="ID_User"/>
    </property>
    <property name="IdSession">
        <column name="ID_Session"/>
    </property>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And both configuration files are on the same folder.

Comment: Please post your SPring conf xml file and especially Hibernate configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are giving absolute path to the file location on disk (e.g. c:/mapings/pool.hbm.xml), it will not work, because it searches for mapping on a class path. Mapping file should be inside your jar or in IDE class path.

Comment: But if it is not a web application, where should I put this config files? In the same file with the classes?

Comment: Yes, it should be in the same folder as your classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Tomcat + web project, you should create resource folder inside your src folder and put your mapping files there it will be equal to:

```
 <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
          <value>object.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<property name="mappingResources" value="pool.hbm.xml" />
```

and put `pool.hbm.xml` in the root of your classpath. I.e. your `bestofs.persistence.PoolBean` will be in a directory structure like `<somewhere>/bestofs/persistence/PoolBean.class`. The mapping file should be inside `<somewhere>`, right alongside `bestofs`.

That's all you need to do unless you have some strange ClassLoader magic happening.